# How do you export a selection of files from the Synchronize view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Sometimes I have made some local changes and for whatever reason don't want to commit them to the source repository.  In this case I like to zip up and save off my changes on my local file system until I am ready to commit them at a later date.

I recall that in an earlier version of eclipse, there was a context sensitive action from the Synchronize view that would highlight in the Navigator view the same files that you have selected in the Synchronize view.  Then from the Navigator view, you can choose to export the highlighted selection.

I don't see where that option is still available from the Synchronize view anymore and manually selecting the files in the Navigator/Package Explorer view is tedious.  Is there an easy way to export a selection of files within the Synchronize view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not on the context menu, but going to the Navigate menu up top and selecting "Show In->Navigator" will apply that selection.  Whether or not you can export just the selected files, I don't know.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at *the Change Sets* feature.

On the synchronize view, the very last button is the Change Sets button - if you turn that on, you can assign your changes to sets that you define (right click on a file listed and then *Add To -> New Change Set*.

I set up a change set called *Local changes*, and then a new change set for each defect/feature I am working on (and set this to be the default change set). When it comes time to commit the changes for a feature or defect, I just right click on the appropriate change set name and click *commit*.

This way you can keep local changes around as long as you like without worrying about sorting which files need committing and which to keep around (or create a patch from etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting key shortcut for export and using it while having relevant files selected pretty much everywhere in Eclipse including synchronize view.

Go to Windows > Preferences > General > Keys search for "Export" and bind it to a key. Don't forget to set "When" to "In Dialogs and Windows".

Comment: Finally, a solution that works for me. Don't forget to check if there is already a shortcut using the keys you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a Patch exactly what you need? There should be a **Create Patch** context menu item in the Synchronize view and it creates a file with all your changes to the selected source files. You can easily reapply the patch later with **Apply Patch**.

Comment: I'm not sure a patch is appropriate in this case. My understanding is that patches are intended to be applied against a specific snapshot. I will want to reapply my changes against a future snapshot and may need to merge.  Maybe it could work, but I prefer to manually resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

the idea of using Change Sets is nice. If you want to export all files that are linked to a change set do this:

Synchronize View >> select the change set >> File >> Export... >> General >> File System >> Next >> all files of the change set are selected now >> select "Create Directory structure for files" and a "To directory" for the export >> Finish

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do in eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0)

Suppose, I am working on an issue of Primeface Upgrade and a new issue came. I need to take a backup of the existing changes related to the PF upgrade to a specific changeset, say *upgrade* first. Following is the process

1. Open Team Synchronizing perspective
2. On the synchronize view, the very last button is the Change Sets button, turn that on
3. Select all the files which should be part of the changeset *upgrade*. Right-click on a file listed and then Add To/Reassign Changes To -> New Change Set -> Give name as *upgrade* -> Select "Enter a Commit comment" -> Enter Commit comment -> click Ok
4. Add all the files which should be part of the changeset using the same method
5. Right-click on the changeset *upgrade* -> create path -> Save In File System -> Chose location and file -> Choose Workspace -> Finish
6. Above step will create the patch file which we can reapply to get the effect of the changeset
7. To reapply: right click on the version where the changeset will be applied -> Team -> Apply Patch -> Choose File -> Select the path file -> Next -> Check all the changes are imported -> Finish.
8. After my work each day, I take daily back up of this patch file only using step 5